# How can I make a simple fadeToggle nav/site using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn some basic Javascript. I've got three simple buttons. I want to click the events button, hide the contact and media containers and display the events container. Here's what I'm working on...

```
$(".events, .events-close").click(function(){
    $(".contact-container, .media-container").fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(".events-container").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post your relevant HTML

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". Specifically, what's happening that you don't want to happen, what's not happening that you do want to happen, etc..

Comment: Looks like it works fine, assuming your HTML is alright... https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/u6yfooxz/2/

Comment: http://gregghooker.co.uk/tlgt/

Test site link. I'll try and more detail to my question next time. @mhodges

Comment: @Santi that fiddle doesn't look like it's working correctly. I've added a link to the test site above

Comment: Edit your question to include the details, rather than comments. Additionally, your example *should not depend on external resources* - a question must have a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example *in the question itself*. In regards to the fiddle not working correctly, you'll need to elaborate. Your question states *"...click the events button, hide the contact and media containers and display the events container."* - Is this not what the fiddle does? https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/u6yfooxz/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see you have three buttons ok... and you want to handle the `click events` of each button right? then... on the click event you want to show/hide some `<div>`?

This is a simple example...

```js
$(function(){

// Let's handle the buttons events
$('#btnContact').on('click', function(){
 $("#divContact").fadeIn('slow');
 $("#divMedia").hide();
 $("#divEvents").hide();

});
$('#btnMedia').on('click', function(){
 $("#divContact").hide();
 $("#divMedia").fadeIn('slow');
 $("#divEvents").hide();

});
$('#btnEvent').on('click', function(){
 $("#divContact").hide();
 $("#divMedia").hide();
 $("#divEvents").fadeIn('slow');

});
});
```

```css
.hideDiv{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Example</title>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- JQuery 1.12.4 Google Hosted Library  -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <!-- The buttons -->
   <button id="btnContact" class="events btn btn-success">Contact</button>
   <button id="btnMedia" class="events btn btn-warning">Media</button>
   <button id="btnEvent" class="events btn btn-danger">Events</button>
  </div>
  <!-- your divs... -->
  <div class="row hideDiv" id="divContact">
   <h3>Contact</h3>
   <p>Your HTML content here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row hideDiv" id="divMedia">
   <h3>Media</h3>
   <p>Your HTML content here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row hideDiv" id="divEvents">
   <h3>Events</h3>
   <p>Your HTML content here...</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a great example! Thank you Fernando. I would however like to get some FadeIn and FadeOut effects on the containers. But I'm assumin If I applied Fades to your example it wouldn't work? I'd need to fadeOut the container that's currently showing before fading in the next?

Comment: Sure! I've edited the code, check it out, now have "fadeIn" effect :)

Comment: That's perfect Fernando! You smashed it! Thank you so much, I'm such a noob with Javascript and you've been so clear and concise.

Comment: Although it does present an issue with the black background. They unfortunately flash. I've updated the test site: http://gregghooker.co.uk/tlgt/

Answer (score 0):

assuming you just have to use the toggle for all xxx-containers. since you want to toggle all of them with buttons which have the classes .events and .events-close
here is the js:

```
$(".events, .events-close").click(function(){
  $(".contact-container").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
  $(".media-container").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
  $(".events-container").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
});
```

and in css you simply do:

```
.events-container {
  display: none; //this makes the container "invisible" at page load time
}
.media-container {
  opacity: 100; //this makes the container "visible" at page load time
}
.contact-container {
  opacity: 100; //this makes the container "visible" at page load time
}
```

since the fadeToggle method is manipulating the opacity attribute of an element by increasing it or decreasing it depending on its actual value.

look at the documentation of .fadeToggle() : [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)

it says:

> The .fadeToggle() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. When called on a visible element, the element's display style property is set to none once the opacity reaches 0, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

hope i could help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Surely that would open and close all of the containers at the same time.

Comment: yes it do the following: " hide the contact and media containers and display the events container." as in your question... just try it in a fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u6yfooxz/4/)

Comment: Sorry no that's not working how I want. My question wasn't clear and I will endeavour to be clearer next time. Test link is here: http://gregghooker.co.uk/tlgt/ 

Fernando has nailed the functionality I want but doesn't have the fade effects.

Comment: That works better but It's still not correct. You can see the divs jumping. See  the test site link. I want the functionality of the contact button across all nav buttons similar to Fernandos example

Comment: then just add `position: absolute;`  as css attribute to the containers. see this fiddle: [without jumping divs](https://jsfiddle.net/ct92rmj4/)